Debug problem on likelihood function of cox proportional hazard model
This is a homework problem and it's very easy if you use coxph() function in R.

In Example 7.9, data from a clinical trial of chemotherapy and chemotherapy combined with radiotherapy in treating locally unresectable gastric cancer is given. Of interest in this study is a comparison of the efficacy of the two treatments on overall survival.


(a) Using an appropriate proportional hazards model, test the hypothesis of difference in survival between the two treatment regimes. Find a 95% confidence interval for the relative risk of death for patients treated only with chemotherapy compared to patients treated with chemotherapy plus radiation.


(b) Confirm that the hazard rates for the two treatment groups have nonproportional hazards using a time-dependent covariate in the proportional hazards model.

However, I'm trying to manually construct partial loglikelihood functions for cox model(using breslow method for ties) with or without time-varying variables for some practicing. And things go wrong if any of continuous variables included.
My codes read:
library(survival)
library(ClinicalTrialSummary)
data(ggas)
ggas$day <- ggas$time*365
ggas$trt <- abs(ggas$group-1)

# a
# built-in function
mod1 <- coxph(Surv(day, event) ~ trt, data = ggas, ties = "breslow")
summary(mod1)

# manual function
time_failure <- unique(ggas[ggas$event == 1,][["day"]])
numerator <- vector(mode = 'double', length = 80)
denominator <- vector(mode = 'double', length = 80)

minus_loglikeli_9.3_a <- function(p){
  b1 <- p[[1]]
  
  for (i in 1:80) {
    numerator[[i]] <- 
      sum((ggas[ggas$day == time_failure[[i]] & ggas$event == 1,][["trt"]] * b1
      ))
  }
  
  for (i in 1:80) {
    denominator[[i]] <- 
      nrow(ggas[ggas$day == time_failure[[i]],])* 
      log(sum((exp(ggas[ggas$day >= time_failure[[i]],][["trt"]] * b1
      ))))
  }
  minus_loglikeli_9.3_a <- -sum(numerator - denominator)
}

opt_9.3_a <- optim(par = 1, minus_loglikeli_9.3_a, hessian = TRUE, method = "Brent", lower = -10, upper = 10)
opt_9.3_a$par

# b
# built-in funciton
mod2 <- coxph(Surv(day, event) ~ trt + tt(trt), data = ggas,
              tt = function(x, t, ...){x * log(t)}, ties = "breslow")
summary(mod2)

# manual function

minus_loglikeli_9.3_b <- function(p){
  b1 <- p[[1]]; b2 <- p[[2]]
  
  for (i in 1:80) {
    numerator[[i]] <- 
      sum((ggas[ggas$day == time_failure[[i]] & ggas$event == 1,][["trt"]] * b1 +
           ggas[ggas$day == time_failure[[i]] & ggas$event == 1,][["trt"]] * b2 * log(ggas[ggas$time == time_failure[[i]] & ggas$event == 1,][["day"]])
           ))
  }
  
  for (i in 1:80) {
    denominator[[i]] <- 
      nrow(ggas[ggas$day == time_failure[[i]],])* 
      log(sum(exp(ggas[ggas$day >= time_failure[[i]],][["trt"]] * b1 +
                   ggas[ggas$day >= time_failure[[i]],][["trt"]] * b2 * log(ggas[ggas$day >= time_failure[[i]],][["day"]])
      )))
  }
  minus_loglikeli_9.3_b <- -sum(numerator - denominator)
}

opt_9.3_b <- optim(par = c(1, 1), minus_loglikeli_9.3_b, hessian = TRUE)
opt_9.3_b$par

The result is:
> summary(mod1)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(day, event) ~ trt, data = ggas, ties = "breslow")

  n= 90, number of events= 82 

       coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)
trt -0.1059    0.8995   0.2234 -0.474    0.635

    exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
trt    0.8995      1.112    0.5806     1.394

Concordance= 0.562  (se = 0.031 )
Likelihood ratio test= 0.22  on 1 df,   p=0.6
Wald test            = 0.22  on 1 df,   p=0.6
Score (logrank) test = 0.22  on 1 df,   p=0.6

> opt_9.3_a$par
[1] -0.1058902

> summary(mod2)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(day, event) ~ trt + tt(trt), data = ggas, 
    ties = "breslow", tt = function(x, t, ...) {
        x * log(t)
    })

  n= 90, number of events= 82 

            coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)   
trt     -3.86723   0.02092  1.47724 -2.618  0.00885 **
tt(trt)  0.64681   1.90943  0.24795  2.609  0.00909 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

        exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
trt       0.02092    47.8096  0.001156    0.3784
tt(trt)   1.90943     0.5237  1.174486    3.1043

Concordance= 0.576  (se = 0.03 )
Likelihood ratio test= 8.55  on 2 df,   p=0.01
Wald test            = 6.87  on 2 df,   p=0.03
Score (logrank) test = 7.59  on 2 df,   p=0.02

> opt_9.3_b$par
[1] -25.801859  -3.475625

As you can see, the result is very close for question a but different for question b. I've tried to create a new continuous predictor and add it into model. The result of coxph() and my own function is very different.
I check my codes for several times and have no ideas what is wrong with it. Hope anyone could help me a sort it out. :)
